# Counting frequency of each element in array - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm counting the customer occurrences using reduce like this. Then, I need to display the customer who appear more than 3 times. It works actually, but only display the count because I'm using `map.values()`. I want it to display the customer name too. Anyone know how to do it? thank you!

```js
const customer = ["Andy", "Drew", "Andy", "Brian", "Andy", "Brian", "Andy", "Brian", "Brian", "Drew", "Brian"];
const custFreq = customer.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.set(curr, (acc.get(curr) || 0) + 1), new Map());
const result = [...custFreq.values()].filter((curr) => curr >= 3.0);
console.log(result);
```

```
result => { 4, 5 }
expected result => { Andy: 4, Brian: 5 }
```

Comment: actual result of execution of your code is [4, 4] but not a {3, 5}

Comment: @Yana Trifonova my bad, I'll edit it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the `name` and `count` whose `count` is greater than `3.0`

Since there is a typo on `7` element i.e. `"Brian,"`. That's why it is giving out `count` of `Brian` as `4` instead of `5`

```js
const customer = [
  "Andy",
  "Drew",
  "Andy",
  "Brian",
  "Andy",
  "Brian",
  "Andy",
  "Brian,",
  "Brian",
  "Drew",
  "Brian",
];
const custFreq = customer.reduce(
  (acc, curr) => acc.set(curr, (acc.get(curr) || 0) + 1),
  new Map()
);
const result = [...custFreq.entries()].reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  if (value >= 3.0) acc[key] = value;
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

**EFFICIENT SOLUTION: Only need to iterate `customer` array only once**

```js
const customer = [
  "Andy",
  "Drew",
  "Andy",
  "Brian",
  "Andy",
  "Brian",
  "Andy",
  "Brian,",
  "Brian",
  "Drew",
  "Brian",
];

const result = {};

const custFreq = customer.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr] = (acc[curr] ?? 0) + 1;
  if (acc[curr] >= 3) {
    result[curr] = acc[curr];
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(custFreq);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It works, thank you! I used entries before, but I'm do it wrong so it return "filter is not a function" error.

Comment: @man99 One more efficient solution added. Check it out...

Answer (score 2):

You could always use `entries` instead of `values` and `Object.fromEntries` to convert back to an object.

```js
const customer = ["Andy", "Drew", "Andy", "Brian", "Andy", "Brian", "Andy", "Brian", "Brian", "Drew", "Brian"];
const custFreq = customer.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.set(curr, (acc.get(curr) || 0) + 1), new Map());
const result = Object.fromEntries([...custFreq.entries()].filter(([_,count]) => count >= 3.0));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `Object.keys` with `.filter` to achieve that:

```js
    //Combination of keys and filter
    const customer = ["Andy", "Drew", "Andy", "Brian", "Andy", "Brian", "Andy", "Brian", "Brian", "Drew", "Brian"];
    let custFreq = {};
    customer.forEach(item => {
        if (!custFreq[item]) custFreq[item] = 0;
        return custFreq[item]++;
    });
    console.log((Object.keys(custFreq).filter(item => (custFreq[item] > 3))).map(item => {return {[item]: custFreq[item]}}));
```